# selecting one element on click event

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I 'm trying to change the class of the selected row in a table. Each row has the same class name to begin with.  The class name changes whenever the user clicks on the image. 
(think of gmail's starred/not starred email)

i have the following code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".notSelected").click(function() {
    $(".notSelected").removeClass(".notSelected").addClass(".selected");
    });
});​
```

EDIT:  I want to mark/highlight each selected row.
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J8Ehr/)

Any suggestions on how to tackle this problem?
thanks

Comment: Which problem? Is your code not working correctly? What exactly is happening and what do you expect to happen?

Answer (score 2):

This will change class when someone clicked on `.notselected` and change it into 'selected'. Remove and AddClass need to be without the dot. Furthermore you class name was notselected instead of notSelected.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".notselected").click(function() {
     $(this).removeClass("notselected").addClass("selected");
    });
});​
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/J8Ehr/1/

BTW take a look at [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) maybe it will help you to define this in another way.

Another remark: You want to change the the row class, the above answer will only change the field class. If you want to change the class of the row try something like this (not tested):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".notselected").click(function() {
     $(this).parent('tr').removeClass("notselected").addClass("selected");
    });
});​
```

Comment: Actually, the syntax is correct but the logic is wrong (in the OP's code).

Comment: The removeClass and AddClass don't require a . before the class. Also the name of the class is notselected instead of notSelected.

Comment: Uh, I did not notice the problem with the class names. You can still argue whether it's a syntax error or not ;) You should explain in your answer what is wrong exactly, that would certainly be more helpful.

Comment: Once I select row 1 & then select row 2, it removes the "selected" class from row 1. How do I save the row 1 which was selected before row 2?

Answer (score 1):

Your elements have `notselected` class names, and your selector tries to find elements with class of `notSelected`, also you should not use `.` with `addClass` and `removeClass` methods.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".notselected").click(function() {
        $('.notselected').removeClass('selected')
        $(this).addClass("selected")
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sxY6z/

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".notselected").click(function() {
    $(".selected").removeClass("selected").addClass("notselected");
    $(this).removeClass("notselected").addClass("selected");
    });
});​
```

Two problems. One, your applied class was `notselected` not `notSelected`. Two, you don't need a `.` in the removeClass argument. Also, you had MooTools loaded in your original fiddle, instead of jQuery.

http://jsfiddle.net/J8Ehr/6/

Answer (score 0):

[The name of](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/J8Ehr/3/) the class is sufficient to add/remove . Remove the dot prefixed to it..

Also set the **s** to lowercase for **notselected** class

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".notselected").on('click',function() {
        $('.notselected').removeClass("notselected")
            $(this).addClass("selected");
    });
});​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/J8Ehr/3/)

Comment: This will remove the notselected class from all elements.